# WebExtensions (Firefox): communicating between content and background script

Tags: messaging, firefox-addon-webextensions

I've just started developing my first WebExtension-based Firefox AddOn, and I have trouble understanding the concept of communicating between content script and background script as described here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_scripts#Communicating_with_background_scripts

I've stripped down the "One-off messages" example to be even simpler (just send the href of the first link to the background script), but it still does not work.

manifest:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "CommunicationTest",
  "version": "1.0",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["comm-background.js"]
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*.imdb.com/*"], // use any page as example
      "js": ["comm-content.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

content script:

```
var links = document.links;
if (links.length > 0) {
  var href = links[0].href;
  browser.runtime.sendMessage( { "url": href } );
  console.log('(content)', href);  // this log works.
}
```

background script version 1 (according to Mozilla docs)

```
console.log('background is here ...'); // this log works.
browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(notify);
function notify(message) {
  console.log('(background) ' + message.url);
}
```

background script version 2 (found in the web)

```
console.log('background is here ...'); // this log works.
browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener( function(message,sender,sendResponse) {
  console.log('(background) ' + message.url);
});
```

As you see in the comments, some of the console logs work. This means the AddOn is loaded and running. I'm testing it as temporary AddOn in about:debugging.
The other console logs do not work. But I've got an error message in the console:

> Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.

I guess I must have missed a basic detail in the docs.

Comment: Did you add both your content script and your background script to the manifest? Can you attach the addon you have right now to this question?

Comment: Yes, I did. Otherwise I would not have had the console logs from both sides. I just added the manifest to the question.

Comment: Try to wrap your content script in a DOMContentLoaded event.

Comment: Ive tried it according to this example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded but I don't even get the console log 'DOM fully loaded and parsed'. I think it's because the content script is loaded _after_ this event, so it will never see it.

Comment: After the "js" property, specify "run_at": "document_start" to make sure the content script is loaded fast enough to catch the DOMContentLoaded event.